# I'm trying to fetch a nested API and render it to the UI using react state. Even after a successful fetch i'm not able to access the nested json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying access data from a nested API, put the data in a state variable (UI) and render it to the user interface by fetching
"http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/news"
here is a portion of the return JSON data

```json
{
  "header": "NCAAF News",
  "link": {
  "language": "en",
  "rel": [
  "index",
  "desktop",
  "league"
  ],
  "href": "https://www.espn.com/college-football/",
  "text": "All NCAAF News",
  "shortText": "All News",
  "isExternal": false,
  "isPremium": false
  }
}
```

```
async function get() {
    let get = await fetch("http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/news");
    let result = await get.json();
    return result;

}

export default function App() {

    const [UI, setUI] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        get().then((final) => {
            setUI(final);
        })
    })

    return (
        <>
        {UI.rel.map(result => <p>{result}</p>)}
        </>

    )
}
```

I'm using `{UI.rel.map(result => <p>{result}</p>}` to access and map the array (UI.rel) array but I'm getting an error saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

I've tried accessing other nested JSON data using other methods with no issues but this particular piece of data is not working

Comment: add in return 

return (
    <>
    { UI && UI?.rel.?map(result => <p>{result}</p>)}
    </>

)

Comment: i've used your suggestion and i'm still receiving "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". When I console.log the json data I able to view so I know the fetch is succesfull.

Comment: can you tell me the result of log in this code.


    useEffect(() => {
        get().then((final) => {
          console.log('final ===>', final);
            setUI(final);
        })
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UI` is *an array*:

```
const [UI, setUI] = useState([]);
```

It may be updated to some other value later, but initially it's an array.  And you're trying to use that array like this:

```
UI.rel.map(result => <p>{result}</p>)
```

An array has no property called `rel`, so that property is `undefined`.  And you can't call `.map()` on `undefined`.

One approach could be to initialize `UI` to an object with a `rel` property that you expect, for example:

```
const [UI, setUI] = useState({ rel: [] });
```

Alternatively, you could initialize it to `undefined`:

```
const [UI, setUI] = useState();
```

And conditionally render based on whether or not it has a value:

```
<>
  {UI && UI.rel.map(result => <p>{result}</p>)}
</>
```

---

**Edit:**

Also, *examine your data structure*:

```
{
  "header": "NCAAF News",
  "link": {
    "language": "en",
    "rel": [ "index", "desktop", "league" ],
    "href": "https://www.espn.com/college-football/",
    "text": "All NCAAF News",
    "shortText": "All News",
    "isExternal": false,
    "isPremium": false
  }
}
```

You forgot the `link` property in the object hierarchy.  So the above would need to include that.  For example, in the first approach:

```
const [UI, setUI] = useState({ link: { rel: [] } });
```

And in either approach:

```
<>
  {UI && UI.link.rel.map(result => <p>{result}</p>)}
</>
```

When working with any data structure, it's important to examine and understand that data structure.

Comment: i've used both of your suggestions and i'm still receiving "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". When I console.log the json data I able to view so I know the fetch is succesfull.

Comment: @chose: Are you sure this is the line of code producing that error?  Can you update the question to include the new updated code, ideally as a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @chose: In your JSON data... Is `rel` really a top-level property?  Or is it a property of `link`?  Overall it sounds like you're just not understanding your own data.  **Edit:** See updated answer.

Comment: We have many, many duplicates of this question around...

Comment: @David Thank you for your contribution and your attention to detail. Omitting the link property was the issue all along.